# Почему у меня ошибка "list index out of range"?

Tags: python

Дан файл `f`, компоненты которого являются действительными числами. Нужно найти разность первой и последней компонент файла.

```
f = open("input.txt", "r")
a = list(map(float, f.read().split()))
print(f"{(a[0] - a[-1]):.3f}")
f.close()
```

Comment: ваш код рабочий. как выглядит `input.txt` ?

Comment: Вероятнее всего, файл пустой.

Comment: Числа то чем разделены? Если каждое на отдельной строке, то нужно `splitlines` использовать.

Comment: Dmitry, я просто в одну строку написал 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 3